# Deserialize JSON of Hierarchy

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

To deserialize the following  Json I have used the following combination of classes so i can then four loop the hierarchy
but it does not work

I have not found any tutorial for deserializing such json
Any help is highly appreciated

```
var myFoo = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Commn.foo2>(@"
{""root"":
    {""qss"":[
        {""id"":""d1"",""qss"":[
            {""id"":""qs1-1"",""tp"":""50px"",""ck"":""i"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs1-2"",""tp"":""100px"",""ck"":""i"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs1-3"",""tp"":""150px"",""ck"":""c"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs1-4"",""tp"":""200px"",""ck"":""i"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs1-5"",""tp"":""250px"",""ck"":""c"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs1-6"",""tp"":""300px"",""ck"":""c"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs1-7"",""tp"":""350px"",""ck"":""i"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs1-8"",""tp"":""400px"",""ck"":""i"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs1-9"",""tp"":""450px"",""ck"":""c"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs1-10"",""tp"":""500px"",""ck"":""c"",""dp"":""at""}]
        }

        {""id"":""d2"",""qss"":[
            {""id"":""qs2-1"",""tp"":""50px"",""ck"":""i"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs2-2"",""tp"":""100px"",""ck"":""c"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs2-3"",""tp"":""150px"",""ck"":""c"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs2-4"",""tp"":""200px"",""ck"":""i"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs2-5"",""tp"":""250px"",""ck"":""c"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs2-6"",""tp"":""300px"",""ck"":""c"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs2-7"",""tp"":""350px"",""ck"":""c"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs2-8"",""tp"":""400px"",""ck"":""i"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs2-9"",""tp"":""450px"",""ck"":""c"",""dp"":""at""},
            {""id"":""qs2-10"",""tp"":""500px"",""ck"":""c"",""dp"":""at""}]
        }
    }
}
");

public  class Pages
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public qss[] children { get; set; }
}

public class qss
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string tp { get; set; }
    public string ck { get; set; }
    public string dp { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Holding the root elemnt
/// </summary>
public class foo2
{
    public qss[] root { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: check out [Json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Do you think to edit your question? since your json is not valid

Comment: L.B , It is not could you explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes you're using don't exactly map to the attributes of the JSON file.  Each Object of the JSON (those appearing between the {}) and each array (those appearing between the []) need different class.  Each pair, an member of that class.

```
public class MainObject
{
    public Root root { get; set; }
}
```

This class holds the entire "root" value.  Root is defined as such because "root" appears between {}, and the entire string after "root": is it's value.

```
public class Root
{
    public List<OuterQSS> qss { get; set; }
}
```

This class holds the entire outer "qss" value, that appears before the second "qss" which is an array.

```
public class OuterQSS
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<InnerQSS> qss { get; set; }
}
```

This class holds both the "id" value, and the entire array for the inner QSS members.

```
public class InnerQSS
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string tp { get; set; }
    public string ck { get; set; }
    public string dp { get; set; }
}
```

This class holds all that sweet, sweet data in the inner QSS array.

Just replace the type that it's

```
Deserialize<Commn.foo2>
```

method to the new main class

```
Deserialize<MainObject>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation i didn't know that, Now it gives me this error Invalid array passed in, ',' expected. (932):  any idea ?

Comment: There's no ',' separating {""id"":""d1""...} and {""id"":""d2""...}